# Android register for location updates in activity

Tags: android

I have a `singleton` for retrieving `location updates` in my Android project.
This works fine for when I want to use `getters` to get values I need.

However, for one of my `activities`, I need to retrieve location updates as they happen. Is there anyway to "tap" into the `singleton` to retrieve location updates, and process them as I need to inside of the `activity`? Or is there someway to `broadcast` that the location has been updated, and register for `broadcast` updates similar to what I would do in `iOS`?

Here is what I have for my singleton:

```
public class LocationSingleton implements LocationListener {
    //Instance
    private static LocationSingleton mInstance = null;
    private static Context appContext;

    private LocationSingleton(Context context) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, MINIMUM_DISTANCE, this);
    }

    public static LocationSingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            appContext = context.getApplicationContext();
            mInstance = new LocationSingleton(appContext);
        }

        return mInstance;
    }


    /*
     ** Location methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Location", "Provider disabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Location", "Provider enabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Singletons like that are a really bad idea for various reasons.  Why don't you use a `Service` to listen for location updates? That would be a much better solution. What do you mean exactly with tapping into the location updates? Do you want to listen for location updates as long as your `Activity` is open? If yes then you are far better off just implementing this directly in your `Activity`.

Comment: I'm passing the application context. Maybe the singleton was not the best idea, but I wanted a way to collect location data the entire time the app was open (Singleton would store it), and have the option to listen for location updates in particular activities for updating the user on a map.

Comment: That's exactly what the `LocationManager` already does for you. If you really want to listen for location updates independent of any UI then use a `Service`.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Ok thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to "tap" into the singleton

Extend your `LocationSingleton` (bad name btw :) with i.e. listeners so any external code can hook in when it needs live updates. When you receive new location, you just call your listeners. Alternatively (which would be perhaps
cleaner and require less code to write by you) would be to use event bus (like OTTO, GreenRobot's). Your `LocationSingleton` would then emit event on each location update. If any other code would like to know about that, it'd just subscribe to the bus for particular event and that's mostly it. If unsure, go
with Event Bus solution.

Comment: Would keeping the `singleton` to broadcast location updates using the `event bus` be a good solution? Or is there better ways. People seem to be against using a `singleton` for this. I need to broadcast updates the entire time the app is open.